# PDO won't write to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a PHP newbie and I'm trying to write the facebook user id and name to a mysql database. I've been working on it for days but i just cannot write on the database!

this is the code:

```
<?php

include("facebook_constants.php");

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main", 'root', 'password');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test WHERE user_id = :userid");
        $check->bindParam(':userid',$user_profile["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $check->execute();
        $count = $check->rowCount();

        if (!is_null($count)) {
            header('Location: final.php');
        } else {
            $insert = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name, user_id)   VALUES (:name,:userid)');
            $insert->bindParam(':userid',$user_profile["id"]);
            $insert->bindParam(':name',$user_profile["name"]);
            $insert->execute();

            header('Location: final.php');
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}

?>
```

By the way, i tried commenting out the header('Location: final.php') and noticed that the $count variable is always NOT NULL. but when i check the database, its empty.

please excuse my lame coding. =( and thanks so much!

edit:

I've already made it work! (its my high school assignment actually). It appears that i was just using the wrong comparison in the if condition. Thank you so much for the clues!!! ^_^
i don't really understand that well but this worked if($check->fetchColumn() == 0){

thanks again!

Comment: [rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)returns a number no bool

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a code review site. "My code doesn't work" is not the type of question that is asked here. To solve your problem you have to work your code out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet your issue is here:

```
$insert = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name, user_id)   VALUES (:name,:userid)');

$insert = "INSERT INTO test ('name', 'user_id') VALUES (:name, :userid)";
$insert->bindParam(':userid',$user_profile["id"]);
$insert->bindParam(':name',$user_profile["name"]);
$insert->execute();
```

It should look like this:

```
$insert = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name, user_id)   VALUES (:name,:userid)');

// $insert is an object above ^^ but you are overwriting with text here.
// $insert = "INSERT INTO test ('name', 'user_id') VALUES (:name, :userid)";
$insert->bindParam(':userid',$user_profile["id"]);
$insert->bindParam(':name',$user_profile["name"]);
$insert->execute();
```

Comment: Give a man a fish... And he'll make you feed him for free for the rest of his life

Comment: @YourCommonSense I figured my answer would be unpopular but this was a case of a man is using a fishing pole backwards so I merely told him to turn it the right way.

Comment: No. it was a case "I'm a PHP newbie and I want all at once, without learning step by step. So, I put some random lines together, now make them work for me"

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not everyone is cut from the same cloth. There are different learning styles for everyone. Just because you are annoyed does not mean you should try to enforce your boxed vision of users and strike down anyone who deviates. Yes, your point of view holds some value and maybe truth but it is minuscule to me.

Comment: There are still rules on this site to follow, mind you. It is not only to gain you rep.

Comment: @YourCommonSense what led you to the rep conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

your prepared query in `$insert` variable is overridden with the string of the query. so `bindParam()` etc. just do not work

I am talking about these lines:

```
$insert = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name, user_id)   VALUES (:name,:userid)');
$insert = "INSERT INTO test ('name', 'user_id') VALUES (:name, :userid)";
```

Comment: Thank you! It fixed one of the errors i was having.  I removed the second insert but it still won't write. =(

Comment: @rhajell - Try `var_dump($pdo->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($insert->ErrorInfo())` after your `execute()` call. That will print out any error information.

Comment: @andrewsi Thank you for the tip (Sorry, i am just learning PHP and my teacher hasnt discussed debugging yet). I found out that there's something wrong with the value that number of rows is returning. I already fixed it! =)